Solving a system of matrix equations
Let $A$ and $B$ be two symmetric $n\times n$ matrices over complex numbers.
We call the pair $(A,B)$ satisfy condition $(P_k)$ if there is a sequence of vectors $\vec{v_0},\ldots,\vec{v_k}$ not all zero, and satisfy the following $k+1$ equations
$$A\vec{v_0}=\vec{0},\ A\vec{v_1}+B\vec{v_0}=\vec{0},\ldots, A\vec{v_k}+B\vec{v_{k-1}}=\vec{0},\ B\vec{v_k}=\vec{0}.$$
Note $(P_0)$ just mean $A$ and $B$ share a common eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$. Also, it is clear that $(P_k)$ implies $(P_{k+1})$.
My question is: Is the condition  $(P_{k})$ strictly stronger than $(P_{k+1})$? In particular, I want to know if $(P_k)$ with $k\ge 1$ implies $(P_0)$.

It might help to note that $(P_k)$ can be encoded with a single matrix equation:
$$
\pmatrix{A & B}
\pmatrix{v_0 & v_1 & \cdots & v_k & 0\
0 & v_0  & \cdots & v_{k-1} & v_k}
$$

Here is an example that shows that $P_1$ does not imply $P_0$.
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix},\;\;
B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
It is easy to see that there is no common non-zero vector in kernels of $A$ and $B$ (so, $P_0$ is not satisfied), but they satisfy $P_1$ with vectors $v_0 = (1,1,0)^t$ and $v_1 = (0,1,1)^t$.
I think that in general $P_k$ does not imply $P_{k-1}$, but it seems to me that the construction of a counterexample will require matrices of bigger size (something like $n = k+2$ in order to construct a counterexample for $P_k \Rightarrow P_{k-1}$). I could not come up with a simple idea how to make a counterexample.
